# What setting should be used to send 200 request per second in Soapui?

Tags: web-services, soapui, load-testing

I would like to load test a web service. I want to generate a test run comprising of 200 tests per second. I am confused about the options provided by SoapUI.

[image]

Can someone please let me know where I should put values to get the desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For running it for 200 requests per second, you will need to run 200 threads with those requests per second. That makes your thread count to 200, how many times you want to run it depends on you, say for instance 200 which you have put.

i.e considering that there is no delay, each second would be 200 request. Total request will come out to 200*200=40000 requests.

I am unsure about the start and end thread, but you can figure that out what exactly is happening there. My assumption is to put start thread as 1 and end as 200 for your case.

Another option is to use fixed rate strategy instead of thread. More details for this can be found [here](https://www.soapui.org/load-testing/simulating-different-types-of-load.html#1-Simple-Strategy---Baseline--Load-and-Soak-Testing)